# Can i delete Search level text from datatable in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('initComplete', function() {
    angular.element('.dataTables_filter input').attr(
      'placeholder',
      '     Enter a key word...');
});
```

Comment: Can you please more elaborate that what exactly you expecting?

Comment: I want to change search textfield lavel of datatable  which is default "Enter a keyword" .